# C C++ Unexpected Output

Tags: c, type-conversion

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char Roman[] = "IVXLCDM";
    int Num[] = {1,5,10,50,100,500,1000};
    int n = 0;

    do
    {
        Roman[n]=Num[n] ;
        printf("%i\n", Roman[n]);
        n++;
    } while (n<7);

    return 0;
}
```

For above code I expect the output:

```
1
5  
10 
50 
100
500
1000
```

But it's producing:

```
1
5  
10 
50 
100
-12
-24
```

[image: code and output]

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: `Roman` is an array of `char`. The value a signed character can hold is `-128 to 127`. Both 500 and 1000 are too large to store in a char. Why are you overwriting the `Roman` array anyway? You could just as easily print the `Num` array with no issues.

Comment: It's an integer overflow, in other words.

Comment: Choose one language — C and C++ are very different.  Note that one of the answers shows a more idiomatic C++ way of progressing — which is wholly infeasible in C.  This is often the case.  A good answer for C++ is completely different from and wholly incompatible with a good answer for C.

Comment: The mention of the language in the title is unnecessary in any event - that is what tags are for.  Your title should give a clue to the subject of the question, and none of it does that.  Why not simply print `Num[n]`? The `char` array `Roman` serves no purpose, and the initialisation is immediately overwritten without being used.

Answer (score 5):

`char` in your case is an 8-bit signed number, which can only hold the values -128 to 127. When you assign 500 and 1000 to a `char`, it throws out all but the low eight bits of those values. 500 - 512 == -12, 1000 - 1024 == -24.

(The C standard permits `char` to be an 8-bit unsigned number, in which case you would have seen 244 and 232.)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, I would use a map:

```
std::map<std::char, int> romanNumerals{{"I", 1}, {"V", 5}, {"X", 10}, 
                                       {"L", 50}, {"C", 100}, 
                                       {"D", 500}, {"M", 1000}};

for (const auto& [key, value] : romanNumerals) {
    cout << key << ":" << value << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The char type can only hold numbers in the range -128 to +127; 256 in total. Even if you set the type to unsigned char, it still will not be possible to store those last two numbers.

Try;

```
int *Roman = (int*)calloc(7, sizeof(int));
```